# Error: the method getId() is undefined for the type List<Product>

Tags: java

I have a method to create a list of objects of class

```
public List<Product> initProducts(){
    List<Product> product = new ArrayList<Product>();

        Product prod = new Product(product.getId(),product.getItemName(),product.getPrice(),product.getCount());
        product.add(prod);

    return product;
}
```

My Product class is:

```
public class Product {

int ItemCode;
String ItemName;
double UnitPrice;
int Count;

/**
 * Initialise the fields of the item.
 * @param Name The name of this member of product.
 * @param id The number of this member of product.
 * @param Price The price of this member of product.
 */

public Product(int id, String Name, double Price, int c)
{
    ItemCode=id;
    ItemName=Name;
    UnitPrice=Price;
    Count = c;
}

public int getId()
{
   return this.ItemCode;
}

public String getItemName()
{
   return this.ItemName;
}

public double getPrice()
{
   return this.UnitPrice;
}

public int getCount()
{
   return this.Count;
}



/**
 * Print details about this members of product class to the text terminal.
 */
public void print()
{
    System.out.println("ID: " + ItemCode);
    System.out.println("Name: " + ItemName);
    System.out.println("Staff Number: " +UnitPrice);
    System.out.println("Office: " + Count);

}
}
```

I am getting an error that the method `getId()` is undefined for the type `List<Product>`, Similarly for other methods. Please help me out with this error.

Is my statement correct??

```
Product prod = new Product(product.getId(),product.getItemName(), product.getPrice(),  
product.getCount());
product.add(prod);
```

Comment: you should call variable, `products` instead of `product` and you  won't get such confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is my statement correct??

```
Product prod = new Product(product.getId(),product.getItemName(), product.getPrice(),  
product.getCount());
product.add(prod);
```

NO this is incorrect. product is not an instance of class `Product`,rather it is an instance of `List`. List does not have any method called `getId`.

If you want to retrieve the elements from the list and use it to create another instance of you can do something like:

```
Product exisProd = product.get(0);
Product prod = new Product(exisProd .getId(),exisProd .getItemName(), exisProd .getPrice(),  
    exisProd .getCount());
```

But make sure that you have elements in the list, otherwise u may run into exception.
    product.add(prod);

Comment: how do i initialize values to data members of the class Product in the list?

Comment: @user2636475 You have already added an element in the list in your initProduct method. Can you tell me what is your requirement?

Comment: i want to enter some fixed data to Id, itemName, Price and count.. how can i assign them?

Comment: @user2636475 Simply call the constructor like: Product prod = new Product(1,"myProduct",30.45,5);

Answer (score 4):

`product` is a reference of `List`

```
List<Product> product = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

which doesn't have that method

Answer (score 2):

`product` is reference to `List` object.

and `List/ArrayList` has no methosd named `getId()`.

You have written `getId()` method for `Prodct` class , so you can call this method using ref to `Product` class object.

If you want to get any product object form list use `get(int index)` method of `ArrayList`.

eg.

```
Product prod = product.get(0);
String id= prod.getId();
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe, the reason you are facing this issue is more due not following the code conventions, that any other.

Whenever you make a collection of any objects, the convention is to use plurals for reference names of the collection. And singular reference name of the Object itself.
You can find more details [here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)

Below is the re-written code with the code conventions being followed:

Method to create a list of objects of class Product:

```
public List<Product> initProducts(){
    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    Product product = new Product(products.getId(), products.getItemName(), products.getPrice(), products.getCount());
    products.add(prod);    
}
```

Product Class:

```
class Product {

int itemCode;
String itemName;
double unitPrice;
int count;

public Product(int itemCode, String itemName, double unitPrice, int count)
{
    this.itemCode = itemCode;
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    this.count = count;
}

public int getId()
{
   return this.itemCode;
}

public String getItemName()
{
   return this.itemName;
}

public double getPrice()
{
   return this.unitPrice;
}

public int getCount()
{
   return this.count;
}
}
```

Now, it is easy to see, that the products Object (which is of the type List) will not have any methods name getId() or getCount(). Infact , these are methods of the Object contained in the List.

Following conventions will help you avoid, such hassles in futures.